# Merging different .asc rasters located in different folders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm using ArcMap 10.6 and am trying to create a model with model builder to mosaic 3 rasters with the same name located in 3 different folders and repeat the process for all the remaining rasters in the three folders.If you look at the picture, you will see that the rasters are stored in 3 different folders ( named bio_a1, bio_a2 and bio_a3) and I need to mosaic the raster named bio_1.asc together, then bio_2.asc together etc...

I have built a sub model that iterates throught the folders and used collect values to create a list and set the list as a parameter (picture 1). [image: model - picture 1]Then I used the submodel in my main model to create a mosaic. 
I have tried to run the model like that and nothing was mosaiced. So I modified the Iterator within the submodel so it would only retrieve bio_1.asc files (picture 2)[image: picture 2] and I still don't have a mosaic (picture 3).[image: picture 3]

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Try replacing the wildcard from `bio_1` with `*_1`. This should create a list of all bio_1 ascii files that feed into the mosaic raster tool.

Comment: Hi Hornbydd,I just replaced the bio_1 by *_1 and still have the same result: no mosaic is being created. Any other thoughts ? Thanks